# Understanding WebGrid in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, webgrid

I am trying to get to grips with WebGrid in a c# MVC4 project. The following code gives this error...

> Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for
>   'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.WebGrid(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable,
>   System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, string, int, bool,
>   bool, string, string, string, string, string, string, string)' has
>   some invalid arguments

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @{
        List<int> obj1 = new List<int>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        var obj1_i = (IEnumerable<int>)obj1;       
        var grid = new WebGrid(obj1_i);
    }

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried it without the cast to `IEnumerable<int>`?  `List<int>` should implement `IEnumerable<int>`.

Comment: @asymptoticFault, yes I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that WebGrid expects your model to be `IEnumerable<dynamic>`, not `IEnumerable<int>`.  Change your code to the following:

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />

    @{
        List<dynamic> obj1 = new List<dynamic>(){ 1, 2, 3, 4 };     
        var grid = new WebGrid(obj1);
    }

</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml()
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanksbut what did you mean by "be IEnumerable, not IEnumerable"

Comment: Thanks, that got rid of the error but I get a blank screen (it prints a table with rows but no data cells)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't properly format my response.  What I meant was you need IEnerumable<dynamic>, not IEnumerable<int>

Comment: answer to second issue above is answered here... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18368295/webgrid-is-printing-out-an-empty-table