# WebGrid is printing out an empty table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Can anyone see why this simple test website is printing out an empty table (in teh html, a table is getting created with 2 rows (tr) but there are no cells (td) getting produced).

Or how is the best way to go about debugging it

DebugController.cs...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace myproject.Controllers
{
        public class type1
        {
            public String ipAddress;
            public String connectionId;
        }

        public ActionResult Debug2(string arg1)
        {
            List<dynamic> obj1 = new List<dynamic>();
            obj1.Add(new type1 {ipAddress="192.168.1.1", connectionId="123"});
            obj1.Add(new type1 {ipAddress="192.168.1.2", connectionId="345"});

            ViewBag.obj1 = obj1;

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

And Debug2.cshtml....

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(ViewBag.obj1);
    }
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably try something a bit more strongly typed.

Also IIRC you must use properties on your model instead of fields so that the WebGrid helper could pick them up:

```
public class Type1
{
    public string IPAddress { get; set; }            
    public string ConnectionId { get; set; }
}
```

and in your action:

```
public ActionResult Debug2(string arg1)
{
    var model = new List<Type1>();
    model.Add(new Type1 { IPAddress = "192.168.1.1", ConnectionId = "123" });
    model.Add(new Type1 { IPAddress = "192.168.1.2", ConnectionId = "345" });
    return View(model);
}
```

and finally in your strongly typed view:

```
@model IList<Type1>
@{
    Layout = null;
}   
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.1.3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/signalr/hubs"></script>
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(Model);
    }
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        @grid.GetHtml()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, but now it is complaining that "The type or namespace name 'Type1' could not be found " I have added a `@using myProjectNamespace` at the top of the .cshtml but that didnt help

Comment: From what you have shown `Type1` is declared inside the `myproject.Controllers` namespace. Also notice that I used `Type1` instead of `type1` which is semantically more correct name of a class in C#. Make sure you don't have typos.

Comment: Ok changed it to: `@model IList<myProjectNamespace.Controllers.DebugController.Type1>` and it all works! Thanks very much.

Comment: Oh, you have declared your model inside the controller? That's bad practice. I would recommend you moving away your model in a separate file. Then you will be able to directly add `@using` with the namespace of your model.

Comment: yes, it was just a test, I will now try ti get it working in the real thing.